# c# узнать что файл загружен

Tags: c#

День добрый, вот такой вопрос, а как узнать что файл уже загрузился на пк? мне нужно скачать текстовик с сервера, я его качаю через webClient.DownloadFile() и нужно после загрузки отредактировать ее. но беда в том что файл не успевает загружаться

Comment: Что значит не успевает загружаться? Когда метод DownloadFile выполнится - файл уже полностью загружен, можно с ним делать что угодно. Вы из другого приложения/процесса/потока пытаетесь с файлом работать?

Answer (score 2):

Обрабатывать событие WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted Event:

```
public static void DownLoadFileInBackground2 (string address)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    Uri uri = new Uri(address);

    // Specify that the DownloadFileCallback method gets called 
    // when the download completes.
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (DownloadFileCallback2);
    // Specify a progress notification handler.
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
    client.DownloadFileAsync (uri, "serverdata.txt");
}
```